# Can you gamble in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Is there gambling in Grand Theft Auto 5? I have searched all over and cannot find a definitive answer.

While driving around [Vinewood Hills](http://gta.wikia.com/Vinewood_(GTA_V)), I stumbled across a casino near the Vinewood racetrack *(here is a picture I took using snapmatic)*:

[image: Casino Image]
[image: Casino Map Image]

I tried accessing this area but all the doors are locked.

Does anyone know if there is, in fact, gambling? If so, when can you gain access to the casino?

Comment: If you consider the stock market gambling, then yes. I don't know yet though if there is other types of gambling.

Comment: It would make sense to include locked businesses that will/can be added to the game via DLC. I.E. Maybe it will be an expansion.

Comment: No you can't. In plenty of different forums they talk about it. And no player could ever do this... SO sad. R* put yoga but no gambling in it. 
maybe it will come later... i hope it so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest update to GTA V, it is possible to gamble in GTA Online. With the new [Diamond Casino & Resort](https://www.gamesradar.com/gta-online-casino/) update, it is possible to gamble in Grand Theft Auto V's multiplayer player mode GTA Online. It only took six years.

The casino is not available in GTA V story mode, unfortunately.

Comment: FINALLY, ONLY TOOK 6 YEARS! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 18):

No, the only form of gambling in GTA V is betting on the stock market.

However, the casino says "Opening soon" and the other day, while in a helicopter I found a horse/greyhound racing track, so it's possible that these may be added with DLC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please provide credible sources that confirm this?

Comment: Sorry, nothing posted by Rockstar but I have completed the game fully. No missions involve gambling, and it's not unlocked after completition and you can't get in the buildings. The only way they could enable it is with a future update like DLC, or possibly an update when GTA:Online is enabled which unlocks it, so you can go in and either gamble solo or online against other people.

Comment: But you are not a credible source unfortunately. So far, your answer is purely speculative. That is why I voted it down.

Comment: @leetfan You shouldn't downvote answers for that.

Comment: @leetfan If cantsay completed the game (100%) and is on the same system then yes, they are a credible source.

Comment: @Batophobia No it is not since it is pure speculation. He does not know if it will be in a dlc or not. And answers cannot be speculative, that is why questions of speculative nature are prohibited. The hypocrisy is right there. And until he removes the speculation, this is a bad answer and should not be upvoted.

Comment: @leetfan So you are saying the answer just be the first line?  I disagree in that the second part adds additional information for those that may be curious.  When the time of DLC comes along, then the answer can be edited.

Comment: It does not add information, it adds speculation. Have a look at the other answer posted. That is how you do it.

Comment: @leetfan The tooltip for downvoting answers says: "This answer is not useful". This answer conatins 2 pieces of information: **No**, you can't gamble, and **maybe** they'll add it as DLC. This doesn't seem "not useful" to me, as it *does* answer the question *correctly*.

Comment: @Nolonar Speculating about future content or developers intent is offtopic. Therefore, the answer is not useful nor beneficial to the site. Read the rules before you argue please.

Comment: @leetfan "**No**" is not a speculative answer, it's **the** answer to this question. Therefore this answer is not offtopic. Not necessarily the best answer, but a correct one nonetheless.

Comment: @Nolonar How is it not speculating that it might be unlocked with a future dlc? We do not know, there is no announcement regarding this from rockstar. Geez dude.

Comment: @leetfan And how is it not speculating that previous GTA games had gambling? Looks like double standards to me, to be honest. Geez dude.

Comment: @Nolonar Seriously? Because they had and one can prove it. It is a fact that they had gambling. That is what the other answer states and invites the user to draw own conclusion. There is not a single bit of speculation there. Only facts.

Comment: @leetfan And what does that fact add to the answer? Nothing except for speculations that Rockstar *might* add gambling later. And how will they do it, if at all? Through DLC, logically. Seriously, the answer to the question was "no, there is no gambling in GTA 5" which is what both answers stated; anything else is just seasoning.

Answer (score 8):

**The launch-day release of GTA V on the Xbox 360 and PS3 does NOT include gambling or horse racing.**

However there is a history of gambling in GTA, the ability to wager money is first introduced in *Grand Theft Auto: Vice City*, when the player must pay entrance fees for Vice Street Racer events, with a set limit on how much he or she can bet, and perform well enough in the races to break even. In *Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas*, more activities were available that the player can take part in to wager money on in order to gain more money if the player wins the activity or lose the money wagered if the player loses the activity. With its expansion in GTA San Andreas the chances of losing/winning are more probable.

GTA: San Andreas partly took place in Los Santos and had gambling, draw your own conclusions about GTA V post-launch plans.

Comment: This is a proper answer.

Comment: @leetfan Thanks, its good to be back and contributing

Answer (score 3):

You can gamble in the online missions ... bets can be placed on any of the players within the deathmatch / race etc.